# Is anyone implemented layout camera feature like Instagram in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, instagram

I have already tried with single activity and multiple fragment which is added programmatically as per layout(2x2,2x3) same as instagram.

But when i load camera on first fragment its working fine but when it moves to second fragment it stuck.

Used one Camera Fragment with different fragment container as per need.

I have used cameraview by natario1 and cameraX. But in both result not getting as per need.

If anyone done Please give me reference.

Thanks

Below is example of functionality

[Instagram Story Layout Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNT1Y.jpg)

Comment: `same as instagram.` what does instagram do ? what's the functionality you're looking for ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody i have edited question please check.